# How to determine the built in tag of a node in yaml-cpp?

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

In yaml-cpp, the function `YAML::Node::Tag()` seems to only return anything other than `"?"` when an application-defined tag is used in the YAML source. Surely it should return (for example) `"!!map"`, `"!!int"` or other built in tags. Is this desired behaviour, and how can I determine, for example, the particular type tag of a scalar node, e.g. null, boolean, integer, float, string etc.? The only approach I can see is to try `YAML::Node::as<T>()` with each type until an exception is not thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the type of a node, call `YAML::Node::Type()`. The return value is one of:

```
YAML::NodeType::Undefined
YAML::NodeType::Null
YAML::NodeType::Scalar
YAML::NodeType::Sequence
YAML::NodeType::Map
```

yaml-cpp does not do more specific automatic tag detection, e.g., it will not validate `!!int` vs. `!!float`.